# I want map post of custom post type on subdomain

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, subdomain

I am getting problem to access custom post-type on sub domain.

**I have custom post type "school" and I want every post of school post type has own sub-domain.**

For example:

from example.com/vanity123 to vanity123.example.com.

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

There are plugins that do that out of the box: https://wordpress.org/plugins/main-category-as-subdomain/

Make sure you follow the installation instructions.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but I want make post as sub-domain. Please let me know if you have any idea.

Comment: The recommend plugin has been closed, and the proposed solution does not solve the question that is being asked.